# SLF4J2 and Log4J1 to Log4J2

Tags: java, maven, log4j2, open-telemetry

I have been scratching my head over logger dependencies. I want my own code to use the SLF4J 2 API and in tests and runtime use Log4J2 as the provider. However, I have a dependency on OpenLr's binary package that uses Log4J1. Additionally, I want to setup telemetry and have my logs exported.

I found these docs:

- https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html
- https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html
- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/runtime-dependencies.html

It seemed like the correct dependencies would be:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Set SLF4J 2 API version -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Set Log4J 2 API version -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
...
        <!-- Use SLF4J API so logging framework is code independent. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Redirect dependencies using Log4j 1 to Log4j 2 instead. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add logging framework. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <!-- includes log4j-api of same version -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- OpenTelemetry to produce metrics and logs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-api</artifactId>
            <version>${opentelemetry.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencies needed for Geneva export with OTLP agent on docker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${opentelemetry.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
            <version>${opentelemetry.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-log4j-appender-2.17</artifactId>
            <version>${opentelemetry.version}-alpha</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

In another module without opentelemetry these settings seem to work, but in the main project SLF4J can't find a binding. A teammate told me that the following (setting logging to use log4j-reload) works:

```xml
        <!-- Use SLF4J API so logging framework is code independent. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add logging framework. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I'm just not sure why the log4j 2 provider is not working. Is there an incompatability with OpenTelemetry? Please help me understand.

Comment: I wonder if "While we have improved the compatibility of the bridge in the past, applications that try to modify legacy Log4j by adding Appenders, Filters, etc, may experience problems. In this case, migrating those components to Log4j 2 first is recommended." (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api.html) applies

Comment: I assume your dependency is actually using log4j1 stuff so you can't just exclude it?

Comment: Unfortunately excluding log4j1 and log4j-1.2-api results in: ```A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: org/apache/log4j/Logger
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
  at openlr.binary.encoder.LineEncoder.<clinit>(LineEncoder.java:81)```. I am looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70663991/log4j-latest-version-with-slf4j-log4j12) which has some similar configuration.

Comment: I tried replacing `log4j-1.2-api` with `log4j-over-slf4j` but I didn't see any logging output in the project with OpenTelemetry while the other was okay. I created [this issue](https://github.com/tomtom-international/openlr/issues/65) to ask for the dependency to publish a new artifact to Maven. I think we will just have to use log4j-reload for now

Comment: Can you list (e.g. via `mvn dependency:list -DincludeScope=runtime`) all your dependencies containing `commons-logging`, `jcl`, `log4j`, `reload4j` or `slf4j` in their name?